# Was kept waiting or was keep waiting

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct say?

Sentence is in past tense. can we use keep after was or it should be kept?

He was kept waiting for long

He was keep waiting for long

If I Say,

"he was keeps/kept calling me because I was not responding to him"

Is like keeps/kept has been used here as linking verb.

Comment: If that is past tense, what is the present tense? Research?

Answer (score 1):

When BE (*is*, *are*, *am*, *was*, *were* etc) is used as an auxiliary, it can be followed by:

- an *-ing* form, for a "continuous" or "progressive" verb, eg *was keeping*.

or

- a past participle, for a passive verb, eg *was kept*.

No other forms.

I can't think of any contexts or constructions in which *was keep* could be part of a grammatical verb phrase.

Comment: if I say "he was keep/kept calling me because I was not responding to him".  I mean to say keep as linking verb.

Comment: But it's not grammatical, @user4084. _He was_ cannot be followed by _keep_, only by _kept_ or _keeping_. _He was kept_ is passive, so it is not what you want. _He was keeping calling me_ might be grammatical, but not something an English speaker would say. What I think you mean is _He kept calling me_. We don't use _keep_ (in this sense) in the progressive - perhaps because _keep doing something_ already has a repetitive sense.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is

> He was **kept** waiting for long.

The verb *to keep* should be in participle, not bare infinitive.

Comment: Correct on the verb form, but it would be worth pointing out that "He was kept waiting for long" is not a complete/correct sentence.

Comment: He wasn't kept waiting for long. And he was kept waiting for hours.

Comment: Good point, @Lambie: I hadn't noticed that _for long_ is a negative polarity item.

Answer (score 0):

The former sentence is correct, please consider this sentence, taken from a website

> Femi **was kept waiting** on the other side of the fence from the building Mr Johnson was visiting

http://www.brecon-radnor.co.uk/article.cfm?id=110981&headline=Online+anti-Brexit+activist+was+among+crowd+waiting+to+see+Boris+Johnson&sectionIs=news&searchyear=2019

or on the page 428 of the book of "A Biographical Dictionary of Later Han to the Three Kingdoms (23-220 AD)" is written :

> He was sent to Wang Fu the Administrator of Yizhou with a request for six million cash, but **was kept waiting** until formal approval was received from the court

Comment: "Taken from a website" proves nothing. Websites often have wrong information, bad spelling, and ungrammatical sentences. Please add a reference to a reputable source.

Comment: the former sentence?

Comment: @Lambie yes, the former one is right.

Comment: We would say first and second here. former and latter is not clear here.